# When were the Germans aware of British airborne radar during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, united-kingdom

During (and even before) WWII, the British developed [Airborne Interception Radars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_Interception_radar#AI_Mk._IV).

**When** were the Germans aware of these developments during WWII?

I am asking partially because of curiosity and partially because of [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/43934/48266) answer on another SE site.

**I will accept the answer with the earliest date.** I will upvote all answers.

Comment: I'm confused. The answer to the linked question *already* answers your question.  What do you expect of an answer here, short of a direct copy-and-paste?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Actually, I now see why you voted to close. The question has been edited to reflect my original intentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on just *when* you are talking about.  The existence of German AI radar detectors proves the Germans were aware of AI radar; several are documented in various wiki pages: for [Metox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metox_radar_detector) (in 1942, by U-boats), [Naxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxos_radar_detector) (1943, by U-boats and aircraft) and [Flensburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flensburg_radar_detector) (1944, by aircraft).  These  make it clear that for the second half of the war the answer was "yes".

[Thanks to @rs.29 for the Naxos cite.]

A fun read covering this is R.V. Jones *Most Secret War* (or in the US, [*Wizard War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Victor_Jones#Selected_publications)).  The Wikipedia articles cite Brown, Louis (1999). *A Radar History of World War II: Technical and Military Imperatives*, which is less fun but still packed with info.

Comment: +1 and Thanks for answering! As you can see, I made a mistake in the question...

Comment: You might enjoy reading J.V Jones's _Most Secret War_ (or in the US, _Wizard War_) (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Victor_Jones#Selected_publications for details.)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will look into it.

Comment: Even before that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naxos_radar_detector

Comment: Good!  Thanks. The question deserves a  more careful search of the literature than I can deliver.

Comment: @rs.29 You can answer with that and I will upvote.